# Do we need [print-pattern]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I found a one-question-tag [print-pattern] in one of my questions. I believe I was the tag creator, and intent to indicate the question is about printing patterns (e.g.:stars,triangle...) in console. But up to now this tags doesn't used by other questions.

So my question is, do we need [print-pattern] tag to indicate the question is about printing patterns in console? If not, should I remove the tag and let it fade out automatically?

Answer (score 1):

No we don't.

There is only [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627062/how-to-print-a-sector) tagged with it, and I removed it. [It's gone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1tmkAFb_Os).